# Robolectric NoClassDefFoundError with org.apache packages

Tags: android, apache, httpclient, noclassdeffounderror, robolectric

We are trying to integrate robolectric in our project but have runned 
into some unexpected problems.

The project compiles fine when we're not using Robolectric. However, 
we are getting NoClassDefFoundError in the org.apache.http packages 
when running simple tests with Robolectric.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ 
apache/http/HttpRequest 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632) 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616) 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:466) 
        at javassist.Loader.findClass(Loader.java:379) 
        at 
com.xtremelabs.robolectric.bytecode.RobolectricClassLoader.findClass(Robole ctricClassLoader.java: 
60) 
        at javassist.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:311) 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248) 
        at 
com.xtremelabs.robolectric.bytecode.RobolectricClassLoader.loadClass(Robole ctricClassLoader.java: 
37) 
        at se.hsr.android.Info.updateInfoFromWebService(Info.java:57) 
        at se.hsr.android.Info$2.run(Info.java:99) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: caught an exception while 
obtaining a class file for org.apache.http.HttpRequest 
        at javassist.Loader.findClass(Loader.java:359) 
        at 
com.xtremelabs.robolectric.bytecode.RobolectricClassLoader.findClass(Robole ctricClassLoader.java: 
60) 
        at javassist.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:311) 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248) 
        at 
com.xtremelabs.robolectric.bytecode.RobolectricClassLoader.loadClass(Robole ctricClassLoader.java: 
37) 
        ... 11 more 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: shouldn't be modifying 
bytecode after we've started writing cache! 
class=org.apache.http.HttpRequest 
        at 
com.xtremelabs.robolectric.bytecode.AndroidTranslator.onLoad(AndroidTransla tor.java: 
68) 
        at javassist.Loader.findClass(Loader.java:340) 
        ... 15 more
```

We are using maven to build our project and we have included http-client 4.1 (because we are dependent on http-mime 4.1 from the apache 
library).

Since the Robolectric jar as default includes httpclient 4.0.3 we 
can't understand why it can't find the http classes. We assume it has 
something to do with AndroidTranslator trying to modify bytecode (to 
be compatible with the dalvik jvm?)

If someone could shed some light on this matter we would be very 
grateful.

Comment: Your missing the dependencies that the Robolectic jar rely on. Try downloading the Robolectric-all.jar or Robolectric-withDependencies.jar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I fixed it by added the following exclusion

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pivotallabs</groupId>
        <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-RC1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```